# messaging.sendToDevice is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send iOS device notification through my firebase webapp. Am i missing something? i tried messaging.send, getMessaging.sendToDevice, getMessaging.send, literally everything. Tokens are correct.

```
const updates = {};
updates[`users/${annotationUid}/comandePersonali/comandeRichieste/${currentUID}`] = enteredCommessaText;
await update(ref(getDatabase()), updates);

// Ottieni i token APN dal tuo database Firebase
const apnTokensRef = ref(getDatabase(), `users/${annotationUid}/APNs_Tokens`);
const snapshot = await get(apnTokensRef);
const apnTokens = snapshot.val();

if (apnTokens) {

    // Definisci un payload per la notifica
    const apnsPayload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'Nuova comanda',
            body: 'Hai ricevuto una nuova comanda personale.'
        }
        // Altri campi opzionali come data, etc.
    };

    // Invia la notifica a ciascun token APN
    for (const tokenKey in apnTokens) {
        if (apnTokens.hasOwnProperty(tokenKey)) {
            const token = apnTokens[tokenKey].APNs_User_Token; // Ottieni il valore di APNs_User_Token
            console.log(token);

            try {
                // Invia la notifica utilizzando la funzione messaging
                await messaging.sendToDevice(token, payload);
                console.log(`Notifica inviata al token APN: ${token}`);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Errore nell'invio della notifica al token APN: ${token}`, error);
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    console.log('Nessun token APN trovato.');
}


alert("Commessa inviata con successo");
textCommessaPersonaleInput.value = ""; // Cancella il testo dall'input
```

I guess it should just send a notification to devices since APNs works perfectly on the iOS app.

Comment: What is `messaging`?  You haven't shown how you get that object.  Also how are you running this code?  Please edit the question to provide a more [complete](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example) example, and explain how you are running it.  We should be able to duplicate the issue based on the instructions you provide.  If you are referring to some product documentation, please link to the reference you're using.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to run this code in a browser, and **sending** messages is not supported from the browser or other client-side code.

As shown in this [FCM architecture](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/fcm-architecture) diagram:
[image]

Messages can only be sent from the Firebase console and from trusted environments, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or something like Cloud Functions/Cloud Run. To learn more, check the documentation about such [server environments and FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) and on [sending messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message).